# How to quickly mark hard edges?

Tags: edges, zbrush

I'm learning the workflow between zBrush and Blender and lose all of the hard edge marks when transferring from zBrush to Blender, how can I either preserve the hard edges or remark them in Blender quickly?

For example:

1. I created a model in Blender with both hard and smooth edges.
2. I applied a edge split modifier and exported as an .obj to zbrush
3. I applied crease and weld points in zbrush (to transfer the hard edges from Blender)
4. I edited the model in zBrush and exported the file as an .obj to Blender.
5. I opened the file in Blender, the entire model is hard edge because zBrush only works with hard shading. All of the edge marks are lost when imported into Blender again.

I was wondering is there any way to quickly add the marked hard edges back to the new model without manually selecting all of them?

Could I possibly transfer the marked edges from the original Blender model to the new model through a script? Is there some way to separate the model similar to Blender's edge split in zBrush then combine it in Blender (similar to zbrush's weld points)?

Comment: Probably unrelated: Have you tried/Do you use the GoB plug-in to move back and forth between the two?

Comment: Does the reimported model have the same topology? Or does it have a different amout of edges.

Comment: it has the same topology as the original

Comment: @rcgauer I set up the plug-in today and was able to sync the model between zbrush and blender but unfortunately no luck with the edge marks. They are still being lost after the sync. Is there a script to transfer the edge marks from one Blender model to another?

Comment: @Animatoring ... Works great either way.... At least with the current version of ZBrush. You can create in either one and go back and forth.

Comment: @rcgauer You're right, I completely forgot to make it a polymesh first when I was trying to send something from zbrush as a test. Everything works great after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new topology has the same number of edges you can copy them with the [Data Transfer](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Mont29/Foundation/Data_Transfer/Data_Transfer_Manual) modifier.

1. Move both models so they overlap
2. Add the Data Transfer Modifier: Modifiers >> add modifier (to new object without edge marks) >> choose Data Transfer >> [x] Edge Data, enable sharp and nearest edge.